# Vimdiff current line compare

Tags: vim, diff

In Beyond Compare, the line you currently have selected is compared on top of each other at the bottom of the window.  Is there any way to accomplish this in vimdiff?

Comment: Are you referring to, for example, the stuff at the bottom of http://www.scootersoftware.com/moreinfo.php?zz=screenshot&shot=TextCompare , starting with `$body .=`?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer No.

Vim does not have a built in way to do that. You would have to write a plugin that would split two more windows on the bottom, re-size them to 1 line. I tried doing it manually but it didn't keep one of the windows in sync while scrolling.

My work around is to use `CTRL-W J` to move the window to the bottom and then `CTRL-W L` to bring it back to side by side comparison.

see `help: window-moving` for details